# R data.table fread function to suppress warning message

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I want to import some text files with fread. Here is an example:

```
fread(text="a,b\nID_134235,'J'aime'\nID_134235,'J,aime'",quote="'")
```

I have to specify `quote="'"`, because in the second column, I can have `'` or `,` in the text.

Then I have a warning message:

> Warning in fread(text = "a,b\nID_134235,'J'aime'\nID_134235,'J,aime'",
> quote = "'") :   Found and resolved improper quoting in first 100
> rows. If the fields are not quoted (e.g. field separator does not
> appear within any field), try quote="" to avoid this warning.

I don't want to specify `quote=""`, because it changes the nature of the import. I just want to suppress this message. Is there a way to do it.
In fact, I have thousands of files to be read, and R Studio interface seems to dysfonction because of these messages.

Comment: Did you try: suppressWarnings ?

Comment: Try `fread(..., showProgress=F)`?

Comment: Can you provide example rows that triggers the warning?

Comment: example row `ID_134235,'J'aime'` if you put this line in a txt file, you will see the error. I tried suppressWarnings, it is not a valid argument. I also tried showProgress, it doesn't work

Comment: what is your `data.table` version? I can't reproduce this with above example and  `1.14.2`

Comment: Also on 1.14.2, `fread(text="a,b\nID_134235,'J'aime'")` does not produce the error, though that might be because CSV quoting typically uses double-quotes not the single quotes you have there.

Comment: I added an example. Thank you for your comments